# MySQL Row size too large (> 8126)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

After I upgraded MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7 on Ubuntu 14.04, I started to have this problem on certain action. As I understand, the problem is that I am trying to get row that is too big from the table.
So, I managed to solve this problem by limiting columns on select part which was originally using `select *`.

However, I want to solve this problem by changing the setting. (Because I might be able to face a situation where many columns for select are required)

I have tried to change

`innodb_strict_mode = 0
max_allowed_packet = 512M
innodb_log_file_size = 128M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_file_per_table = ON`

all these values but without any luck.

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Sounds like one table was on the verge of hitting the ~8KB limit??

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is the only column that I can think of that grew in size (4 bytes to 5).

Answer (score 2):

Plan A: (see answer by @hmikael)

Plan B: Change `innodb_page_size` to 32K.  However, this is a non-trivial task since it applies to all InnoDB tables.  Doing so would change the limit to ~16KB.

(Note: going to page size of 64KB won't get past 16KB limit per row.)

Plan C: Switch to MyISAM.  *This is not advised for various reasons.*

Plan D: build a "parallel table" or "vertically partition".  That is, split off some of the columns into another table.  Suggest moving rarely-used and/or bulky columns into the new table.  Both tables would have the same `PRIMARY KEY` (though at most one would say `AUTO_INCREMENT`).

Plan E: Shrink datatypes where practical.  That is, don't blindly use `VARCHAR(255)`.  (This will also help with performance in a few situations.)  Don't use a 4-byte `INT` for a true/false flag; use a 1-byte `TINYINT`.  Etc.

Plan F: Normalize common strings.  (A 3-byte `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` is usually a lot smaller than a string.)

Plan G: Don't splay an array across columns.

(Some "Plans" can be used together.)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Add the following to the my.cnf file under 
`[mysqld]` section.

```
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
```

`ALTER` the table to use `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`.

```
ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED 
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;
```

**solution 2** : changed the table storage engine to MyISAM

more details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large

Comment: @RickJames i mean MyISAM instead of InnoDB i just edited my answer thank you for pointed out

Comment: I have already tried solution1, but it does not help. And strange thing is that even though I add `innodb_file_format = Barracuda` on `ect/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`` on ubuntu, when I run `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLES;`, the result still shows some tables still have `Antelope` format. So I had to change involving tables individually.